# How to fix jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What selector do I use to add a class to an `a` element that is inside a `ul > li` of a bootstrap navbar?

Here is [my example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/763h89h9/)

Here is the code:

```
<div class='navbar navbar-inverse' role='navigation'>
    <div class='container'>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'><img src='' height='41' width='40' alt=''></a>
        </div>

        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse'>
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                <li><a class='' id='newsBox'  href=''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-inbox'></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>

<button type='button' id='newsBox2' class='btn btn-default'>asdasd</button>

$("#newsBox2").click(function () {
    $(".navbar .container ul li a #newsBox").addClass(".news");  
});
```

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question

Comment: well i add the example on http://jsfiddle.net/763h89h9/ but i edit the post ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove dot from class param and as ID must be unique on document context, use ID selector only:

```
$("#newsBox2").click(function () {
    $("#newsBox").addClass("news");  
});
```

Comment: LOL, Thanks at the "." is that I have over 10 hours designing for today and my mind is already locked .. apparently it was not to see the point

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned it's better to use the `#newsBox` id.  However, to explain what's wrong with your code, this:

`$(".navbar .container ul li a #newsBox").addClass(".news");`

...should become this:

`$(".navbar .container ul li a#newsBox").addClass("news");`

In the first case you're looking for an element with the id `newsBox` contained *within* the `<a>` element, when it is the `<a>` element *itself* that has `id="newsBox"`

You also are adding ".news" as a class instead of "news"

Comment: But you are still adding a class `.news` not the `news` one

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, fixing it now.

Answer (score 0):

As the `a` you are looking for has the id `#newsBox`, your selector should be

```
.navbar .container ul li a#newsBox
```

You can also just use `#newsBox`